# Error with Javascript on Partial Page Update

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some scripts which needs to be run when partial page changes. On 1st page Load it seems to be working fine but after partial page is updated javascript stopped working

1st Try: 
I tried to put javascript in partial page itself but its not working

2nd Try: 
I tried to put javascript on the parent page from which partial page is upadted

Code To Load Partial Page:

```
@Html.DropDownList("UserType", DirectCast(ViewBag.UserType, SelectList), New With {.onchange = "ChangeUserType(this.value)"})

 <div id="renderTreeView">
        @Html.Partial("_TreeView")
    </div>

<script>
 function ChangeUserType(UserType) {
        $('#renderTreeView').load("/UserMaster/ChangePermission?iUserTypeID=" + UserType);
}
//And Somme of my other javascript function to create tree view
    </script>
```

This script doesnot work on partial page update

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#check-all').click(function () {
            $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', true);
        });
        $('#uncheck-all').click(function () {
            $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.tree li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).children('ul').length > 0) {
                $(this).addClass('parent');
            }
        });

        $('.tree li.parent > a').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
            $(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
        });

        $('#all').click(function () {

            $('.tree li').each(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
                $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
            });
        });
        $('#Add').change(function () {
            AddPermission();
        });
        $('#Change').change(function () {
            AddPermission();
        });
        $('#Delete').change(function () {
            AddPermission();
        });
        $('#View').change(function () {
            AddPermission();
        });
        $('#Print').change(function () {
            AddPermission();
        });

    });

    function SetPageNumber(pageID) {
        var PageID = document.getElementById("pageID");
        PageID.value = pageID
        var PermissionsofPage = document.getElementById(pageID).value
        var AddCheck = PermissionsofPage.charAt(0);
        var ChangeCheck = PermissionsofPage.charAt(1);
        var DeleteCheck = PermissionsofPage.charAt(2);
        var ViewCheck = PermissionsofPage.charAt(3);
        var PrintCheck = PermissionsofPage.charAt(4);
        checkUncheckCheckBoxes(AddCheck, ChangeCheck, DeleteCheck, ViewCheck, PrintCheck)
    }

    function checkUncheckCheckBoxes(AddCheck,
         ChangeCheck,
         DeleteCheck,
         ViewCheck,
         PrintCheck) {
        //$('#Permission input:checked').removeAttr('checked');
        if (AddCheck == 1) {
            $('#Add').attr('checked', true);
        }
        else {
            $('#Add').removeAttr('checked');
            //$('#Add').attr('checked', false);
        }
        if (ChangeCheck == 1) {
            $("#Change").attr("checked", true);
        }
        else {
            $("#Change").attr("checked", false);
        }
        if (DeleteCheck == 1) {
            $("#Delete").attr("checked", true);
        }
        else {
            $("#Delete").attr("checked", false);
        }
        if (ViewCheck == 1) {
            $("#View").attr("checked", true);
        }
        else {
            $("#View").attr("checked", false);
        }
        if (PrintCheck == 1) {
            $("#Print").attr("checked", true);
        }
        else {
            $("#Print").attr("checked", false);
        }
    }
    function AddPermission() {
        var PageIDPermission = document.getElementById("pageID").value;
        var Permissions
        if ($("#Add").is(":checked")) {
            Permissions = "1"
        }
        else {
            Permissions = "0"
        }
        if ($("#Change").is(":checked")) {
            Permissions = Permissions += 1
        }
        else {
            Permissions = Permissions += 0
        }
        if ($("#Delete").is(":checked")) {
            Permissions = Permissions += 1
        }
        else {
            Permissions = Permissions += 0
        }
        if ($("#View").is(":checked")) {
            Permissions = Permissions += 1
        }
        else {
            Permissions = Permissions += 0
        }
        if ($("#Print").is(":checked")) {
            Permissions = Permissions += 1
        }
        else {
            Permissions = Permissions += 0
        }
        var toSet = document.getElementById(PageIDPermission)
        toSet.value = Permissions
    }
</script>
```

This is my Partial Page

```
<link href="~/assets/css/treeview.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="span6">
    <div class="portlet box grey">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption"><i class="icon-sitemap"></i>Page Permission (@ViewBag.PageNo)</div>
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="javascript:;" id="all" class="btn green"> Toggle All</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body fuelux">
            <div class="tree">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a >First Level</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" id="xyz" onclick="SetPageNumber('page_2')">Second Level</a><input type="text" id="page_2" @*style="display:none"*@ value="00000" /></li>
                            <li><a onclick ="SetPageNumber('page_1')">Second Level</a><input type="text" id="page_1" @*style="display:none"*@ value="00000" /></li>
                            <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>First Level</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a>Second Level</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a>Third Level</a></li>
                                    <li><a>Third Level</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a>Third Level</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a>Fourth Level</a></li>
                                            <li><a>Fourth Level</a></li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a>Fourth Level</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a>Fifth Level</a></li>
                                                    <li><a>Fifth Level</a></li>
                                                    <li><a>Fifth Level</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>First Level</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
                            <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="span2" id="Permission">
            <div class="portlet box grey">
                <div class="portlet-title">
                    <div class="caption"><i class="icon-key"></i> Rights</div>
                </div>
                <div class="portlet-body fuelux">
                    <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Add" /> Add
                    </div>
                    <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Change" /> Change
                    </div>
                    <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Delete" /> Delete
                    </div>
                    <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="View" /> View
                    </div>
                    <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Print"/> Print
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="pageID" @*style="display:none"*@ value="0" />
                       @* <button onclick="ChangeCheckBox()">Toggle</button>*@
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The script needs to go in the main view, not the partial. Are you saying the `ChangePermission()` method is not being hit the second time you select an option?

Comment: Not it is being hit As its main view but there are some javascript which handles tree view in partial page which is not loading after second hit

Comment: You have to call the  ChangeUserType through some event like mouseover, mouseclick, kewdown etc... And also have to put the script in parent view..

Comment: ChangeUserType is working well as it doesnot reside in my partialview. What ever reside in my partial view is tree view which doesnot seems to be working as javascript for treeview doesnot work once its loaded

Comment: You should not have any scripts in the partial. And you really should start using unobtrusive javascript (its the 21st century) - `$('#UserType').change(function() {  $('#renderTreeView').load('@Url.Action("ChangePermission", "UserMaster")', {iUserTypeID: $(this).val() });`

Comment: Why are you showing us a script which you are now claiming is working but not showing us the scripts which don't work!

Comment: There is same problem with one of my live application were hover effec stop working from second page its infinite jscroll implemented but there also from second page its hover effect not woorking here is the link -> http://www.anuragplus.com/Product/Index?category_id=1&order_by=New_Arrivals&group_name=Sarees

Comment: Sorry @StephenMuecke I have updated. I dont want to put lot of data in question thats why at first I dint put it now it is on check out

Comment: You should put all your scripts in the main view and use event delegation, e.g. `$('#renderTreeView').on('change', '#Add', function() { ....});`

Comment: I have already put all script in main page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91900/discussion-between-kirtesh-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: I figured out problem is with this code only @StephenMuecke can u plz check the chat

`$('#renderTreeView .tree li').each(function () { 
if ($(this).children('ul').length > 0) { 
$(this).addClass('parent'); 
} 
});`